# Athena count/Sum column divided by count/Sum column returns zero

Tags: sql, group-by, count, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to find percentage based on id column.

issue - I am trying to use count(column)/select count(column) from table which is giving output as 'Zero'

Table name - abc

[image: id tax 123 7.99 124 8.00 125 11.99 126 12 127 21 128 22]

When I use count function to achieve it is returning zero.

This below percentage query always returns zero, tried with many logic.

```
SELECT Count(id) id,
       CASE
              WHEN Cast(tax AS DOUBLE) BETWEEN 7.99 AND    9.99 THEN 'test'
              WHEN Cast(tax AS DOUBLE) BETWEEN 10.00 AND    19.99 THEN 'test1'
              WHEN Cast(tax AS DOUBLE) BETWEEN 20.00 AND    43.69 THEN 'test3'
              ELSE '#N/A'
       END AS "product_category",
FROM   abc
WHERE  Cast(tax AS DOUBLE) BETWEEN 10.00 AND    19.99
AND    id IN
       (
              SELECT id
              FROM   abc
              WHERE  cast(tax double) BETWEEN 7.99 AND    9.99) )SELECT Count(id)/
       (
              SELECT Count(b.id)
              FROM   abc
              WHERE  Cast(tax AS DOUBLE) BETWEEN 7.99 AND    9.99)
FROM   abc
```

if tax between
0 and 10 it is 'test1'
11 and 20 it is 'test2'
21 and 30 it is ;test3'

I am trying to find  a output like below

[image]

Comment: You should please make more clear what you want to do. There is a mistake in your so called "percentage" column. You've written: 1/4 * 100 = 25%. This is incorrect. 25 are 25% of 100 or 1/4 of 100, but 1/4*100 = 25 = 2500%.

Comment: ok sure , I am trying to find the total counts of Id's in (20 to 30) / total counts of id's in (10 to 20) ,   out of 4 people fall under 10 slab , how many of them moved to 20-30 slab.

Comment: And what about `test3` category? What category should be chosen as a reference value to calculate percentage of it?

Comment: ok sure ,  if tax between 
0 and 10 it is 'test1'
11 and 20 it is 'test2'
21 and 30 it is ;test3' . It is kind of slabs .

Comment: You calculate test2 persentage of test1. For test3 should it be a percentage of test2?

Comment: yeah sure, it is also based on test1 , total count of test2/total count of  test1  and total count of test3/total count of test1